# Passing values from one datatable toanother datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How do I pass selected rows to a jquery datatable to another jquery datatable. In one coulmn I have a input number box. I have pass that value to that same table

Comment: please share some html and JS/Jquery code which have so far

Comment: As a function argument... But seriously we need more info.